# Regex for TCP Flags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm running into a problem with this regex for TCP Flag validation.

Here is my current version (I've been though many, all are wrong in some way):

`^([AFPRSU](?![0-9]))(?!\1)|((?<![A-z])[1-9]+[0-9]*)$`

So, the value can either be any non-repeating combination of TCP Flags (A,F,P,R,S,U) or the integer equivalent.

**Valid**:

```
A,
AFP,
FPURA,
18,
1,
40
```

**Invalid**:

```
empty/null/whitespace,
AA,
aFP,
a100,
100a,
XFP
```

The problem with my current regex is the lookaheads/behinds only check one character +/- so `AFPx100` will be a valid value since "F" after "A" is valid. I had similar issues with different iterations, but ultimately it boils down to ignorance. I've been using trial and error on regexr.com but not really getting anywhere, been about 8 hours of effort so far.

I'm unfortunately bound to Regex or I would solve this a different way. At this point I'm desperate for any pointers/advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the anchors to match the whole string, you could match on or more chars out of `[AFPRSU]` or 1 or more digits starting with a digit 1-9 so that also empty strings do not match:

```
^(?:(?![AFPRSU]*([AFPRSU])[AFPRSU]*\1)[AFPRSU]+|[1-9]\d*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the 2 alternatives

  - `(?![AFPRSU]*([AFPRSU])[AFPRSU]*\1)` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 of the same listed characters in the string
  - `[AFPRSU]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rg4INn/1).

```js
const regex = /^(?:(?![AFPRSU]*([AFPRSU])[AFPRSU]*\1)[AFPRSU]+|[1-9]\d*)$/;
[
  "A",
  "AFP",
  "FPURA",
  "18",
  "1",
  "40",
  "",
  " ",
  "AA",
  "aFP",
  "a100",
  "100a",
  "XFP"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`"${s}" --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
);
```

Comment: You answered that incredibly fast. Was there a particular tool you used or you just know your way around regex? I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @JacobBarnes I did not use a tool, I looked at the regex that you used and the valid/invalid strings and I am kind of a regex fan :-)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't try the non-capture groupings, but seeing your example, I see my mistake. Thanks again!